# Haskell - Happy, math expressions and variables parser

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, happy

I'm working on a Happy math expressions and variables parser. The problem is that I don't know how to save the value for a variable and use it later. Any ideas?

This is how I recognize expressions and variables assignment:

```
genExp   : exp                    { $1 }
         | variable '=' exp            { //here I want to save the value of the variable; something like this: insert variables $1 $3, where 'variables' is a Data.Map }
```

A expression can contain a variable. For example:

```
a = 2 + 1
a + 2 (now the parser must print 5)
```

I need to save the value of the variable 'a' when the parser is parsing the line 'a = 2 + 1' and to get the value of the variable 'a' when the parser is parsing the line 'a + 2'

Comment: Erm, this question isn't really clear. Could you rephrase it? A code sample and the actual problem you're trying to solve would be great too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to keep track of the value of variables during *evaluation* of expressions, not during parsing. Let's assume you parse your expressions into the following types:

```
data Expr = Literal Int | Variable Var | Assign Var Expr | Add Expr Expr | ...
newtype Var = Var String deriving (Ord, Eq, Show)
```

Then you could simply pass a Map around your evaluation function with the current value of all variables:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Control.Monad.State

data Expr = Literal Int | Variable Var | Assign Var Expr | Add Expr Expr
newtype Var = Var String deriving (Ord, Eq, Show)

-- Each Expr corresponds to a single line in your language, so
-- a = 2+1
-- a + 2
-- corresponds to
-- [Assign (Var "a") (Add (Literal 2) (Literal 1)),
--  Add (Variable (Var "a")) (Literal 2)]
eval :: [Expr] -> Int
eval es = last $ evalState (mapM eval' es) M.empty -- M.empty :: M.Map Var Int
  where
    eval' (Literal n)  = return n
    eval' (Variable v) = do
      vs <- get
      case M.lookup v vs of
        Just x -> return x
        _      -> error $ "variable " ++ show v ++ " is undefined!"
    eval' (Assign v ex) = do
      x <- eval' ex
      modify (M.insert v x)
      return x
    eval' (Add a b) = do
      x <- eval' a
      y <- eval' b
      return (x+y)
```

Of course, there's nothing to prevent you from evaluating expressions as you parse them, eliminating the need for an abstract syntax tree such as this. The general idea is the same there; you'll need to keep some state with you during the entire parsing, that keeps track of the current value of all your variables.